# Programatically Re-start USB Bluetooth Adapter

Tags: linux, usb, manjaro, usb-drive

Folks I have a usb bluetooth dongle which only works after I remove and re-attach it, can I mount un-mount it from command line to have it to be programmatically re-attached? It is the following device:

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

Comment: It's not a drive, so "mounting and unmountubg" aren't sensible verbs to use here, but you can typically reset the USB bus it's attached to from software

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: roughly, like this: `cd /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/1-11; sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > authorized; sleep 1; echo 1 > authorized'`

Comment: thanks for the reply I seem to have an issue there the device ID changes between boots so I cannot programatically assign it directly